# Xamarin Удалить маркер в google maps

Tags: android, c#, google-maps, xamarin

Пытаюсь показать месторасположение в реальном времени на карте, получаю координаты и вызываю функцию для добавления маркера на карту :

```
public void MyPositions(double Lati, double Longi) 
{ 
    var Mark = GMap.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions().SetPosition(new LatLng(Convert.ToDouble(Lati), Convert.ToDouble(Longi)))); 
}
```

Проблема в том, что когда координаты меняются и добавляется новый маркер, то старый не удаляется. В Marker есть свойство Remove, которое позволяет маркеру удалить самого себя с карты, но как им правильно воспользоваться? Пытался как-то так:

```
Marker Mark;
public void MyPositions(double Lati, double Longi) 
{ 
 if (Mark != null) 
     Mark.Remove();
 Mark = GMap.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions().SetPosition(new LatLng(Convert.ToDouble(Lati), Convert.ToDouble(Longi)))); 
}
```

Но, если переменную объявить глобально, то она покажет только один маркер и новые не добавляются. Как правильно удалить "старый" маркер и поставить новый? Может быть как-то переместить?
 Я искренне надеюсь, что смог донести до вас проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Просто храните все нужные вам маркеры в массиве/списке или чем вам удобнее и обновляйте им координаты при их изменении через свойство Position маркера.

---

А код из вашего комментария я бы переписал так:

```
if (marker == null) marker = GMap.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions());
marker.Position = new LatLng(Convert.ToDouble(Lati), Convert.ToDouble(Longi));
```

Comment: насчет изменения позиции :
`if (marker == null)
                marker = GMap.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions().SetPosition(new LatLng(Convert.ToDouble(Lati), Convert.ToDouble(Longi))));
            //  if (marker != null)
            LatLng latlng = new LatLng(Convert.ToDouble(Lati), Convert.ToDouble(Longi));
           
            marker.Position = latlng;`
я правильно сделал ?

Comment: Думаю удобнее как я дописал в ответе.